# I am trying to figure out how to insert data into my DB using php/mysqli

Tags: php, database, mysqli, insert

This is probably the forth edit on this post so far trying to get some help. I have rewritten this code several times, however nothing seems to work properly. I have been working on this project for about 5 months and still can not find a suitable answer.

Presently, I have been able to get the syntax to work with the exception of inserting data from my form. what gets inserted are null values instead of the string from the input field.

The most recent iteration is:

```
$con = mysqli_connect(host, username, password, db_name1);
if($con->connect_errno){
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $connection->error);
    exit();
}

$query = "Insert into hdd_tracking (`ticket`,`serial`,`vol_name`,`drivetype`,`project`,`notes`,`encrypt_date`,`encryption_password`,`fedX_tracking`,`fedX_rt_tracking`)
 VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
$stmt = $con->stmt_init();

if($stmt-> prepare($query)){

    $stmt->bind_param('isssssssss', 
    $_POST['ticket'],
    $_POST['serial'],
    $_POST['vol_name'],
    $_POST['drivetype'],
    $_POST['project'],
    $_POST['notes'],
    $_POST['encrypt_date'],
    $_POST['encryption_password'],
    $_POST['fedX_tracking'],
    $_POST['fedX_rt_tracking']);
}

$ticket = ISSET( $_POST['ticket']);
$serial = ISSET( $_POST['serial']);
$vol_name = ISSET( $_POST['vol_name']);
$drivetype = ISSET( $_POST['drivetype']);
$project = ISSET( $_POST['project']);
$notes = ISSET( $_POST['notes']);
$encrypt_date = ISSET( $_POST['encrypt_date']);
$encryption_password = ISSET( $_POST['encryption_password']);
$fedX_tracking = ISSET( $_POST['fedX_tracking']);
$fedX_rt_tracking = ISSET( $_POST['fedX_rt_tracking']);

$run = $stmt ->execute();
var_dump($stmt);

if($run){
    $stmt -> close();
    mysqli_close($con);
    }else{
        echo "Failure";
    }
```

The Form is below:

```
<form class="form-inline insertDrive" role="form" name="insert" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
<table class="insertHDD" style="border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 10px;">
    <tr align="left">
        <td>
            <label class="center">Ticket:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="ticket" placeholder="Ticket">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Volume Name:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vol_name" placeholder="Volume Name">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Type:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="drivetype" placeholder="Type">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Project:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="project" placeholder="Project">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Encryption:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="encryption_password" placeholder="Encryption">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Date:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="encrypt_date" placeholder="Date">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label>Serial:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="serial" placeholder="Serial">
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Tracking:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fedX_tracking" placeholder="Tracking">
        </td>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Return:</label>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fedX_rt_tracking" placeholder="Return">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label class="center">Notes:</label>
        </td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <input type="text" width="200px" class="form-control" name="notes" placeholder="Notes">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4">
            <a class="btn btn-small btn-info" name="submit" name="submit">Submit</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

I have made the corrections as from using `id` to `name` and I am still getting the null values. The `var_dump($stmt)` returns:
object(mysqli_stmt)#1 (10) { ["affected_rows"]=> int(1) ["insert_id"]=> int(1262) ["num_rows"]=> int(0) ["param_count"]=> int(10) ["field_count"]=> int(0) ["errno"]=> int(0) ["error"]=> string(0) "" ["error_list"]=> array(0) { } ["sqlstate"]=> string(5) "00000" ["id"]=> int(1) }

Still not getting any where with this.

Comment: Can you describe the problem?  In what way is this failing?  Is the form data being sent to the PHP script?  Are the values what you expect them to be?  Is the database returning an error?

Comment: There aren't any errors, however the initial issue is when the page was being refreshed there were null values being inserted into the DB. Therefore, the connection to the DB is working. however when I try to insert data into the modal form it does nothing.

I am new to PHP/MYSQLI and I am not sure on how to debug the problem. I have tried many different solutions on SO, but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Yes  The problem is you are using `id` where you should be using `name` in the html form `input`s.
For example

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="ticket" placeholder="Ticket">
```

Should be

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" name="ticket" placeholder="Ticket">
```

When using php `$_POST['']` you are accessing the input by name not id

Comment: Thank you for the information. I just tried it and I am still getting null values.

Comment: So I made corrections to the overall PHP script. Instead of using a variable for the query,I have added it to a If statement:    

     if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
 $query = "Insert into hdd_tracking (
 `ticket`,
 `serial`,
 `vol_name`,
 `drivetype`,
 `project`,
 `notes`,
 `encrypt_date`,
 `encryption_password`,
 `fedX_tracking`,
 `fedX_rt_tracking`)
  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

I also removed
$stmt ->.close();

Comment: ...wait, so is it working? If not you could try turning on error reporting.